# Azure Blob Storage: CloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream throws OutOfMemory exception

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

This happens on my Azure Storage Emulator (did not try on real Azure Storage yet). I'm saving files to Blob Storage. I don't have any problem with smaller files (e.g. <= 107 MB). However, for bigger files (e.g. >= 114 MB), I could upload the file without error, but I got out of memory exception when trying to download it.

```
    public Stream GetStream(string fileName)
    {
        var blob = GetCloudBlobContainer().GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        if (blob.Exists())
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
            return stream;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The exception is thrown on call blob.DownloadToStream(stream).

How to fix this problem?

UPDATE:
Okay, I found a workaround for my case. Instead of returning stream, I can make it to save to a local file directly (I need it anyway) using blob.DownloadToFile(), which is working fine. However, I'm still interested in finding a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MemoryStream stores all your data in memory. And the fact that DownloadToFile works for you means that your machine might be running out of memory when trying to store blobs in memory. 
As for uploads, If you upload directly from a file on your file system to blob, we do not load the whole file in memory and so you will not hit the same problem as in download.

Comment: I accepted this answer. However, I don't believe my machine is running out of memory for a file with only 114 MB only.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vinay's answer above, I would make a suggestion that you alternately open the "Performance" & "Processes" tab on your Windows Task manager to monitor memory usage while downloading.